# Is there any way to attach selenium based java doc file in eclipse?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, eclipse

I want to attach java doc file that contains selenium commands & functions so that on hovering to them in my code, i can easily learn about & can use them in better way.
I tried with multiple solutions still found such error,

Open Declaration

```
   WebElement org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(By arg0)
```

Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Comment: I flagged this as off-topic. There are similar questions on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870448/how-to-attach-source-or-javadoc-in-eclipse-for-any-jar-file-e-g-javafx

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is a "Selenium plugin" for your IDE.  I don't think such a thing exists.   **All you get is the default "intellisense" documentation.**  There is no way you can get more than that without a native IDE plugin integration.

The best thing you can do is just reference the official online Javadoc for Selenium  and/or create your own javadoc HTML page for your own Selenium project's classes.

Comment: I guess you're right! I was trying to find the solution as its possible with java & it would be great if it can be possible with selenium also!!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have added selenium jar to the build path, find it the under Reference libraries in Eclipse.

> Right click on the jar->Select Properties->In the "Java Source Attachment" section, select 'Javadoc Location' from the options on the left->Enter the Url to the java doc "http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/"->Click on Apply->Click on OK

Answer (score 0):

Download latest java source from below link
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.48/selenium-java-2.48.2.zip

1. Right Click on Project
2. Build Path => Configure Build Path => Libraries tab
   [image]
3. Edit Source Attachment 
   [image]
4. Give path of above downloaded file path
5. Click OK

Comment: This doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

**Navigate To:**
project properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Selenium-java-2.42.2.jar

**Select** **Selenium-java-2.xx.x.jar** & **Expand** it.

You will see **Javadoc location option**. **Select** it and click on **Edit** button.

On next window add **http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/** link in **javadoc location path** textbox and click on **Ok** button.

For more details [**Click Here**](http://avinashpandeblogsonseleniumautomation.blogspot.in/2016/03/how-to-bind-selenium-javadoc-to-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Package Explorer->Build Path->Configure build path->Selenium-Server-Standalone-3.x.x.jar and expand it->javadoc location->Edit

Copy **http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/** and Paste it in Javadoc location path. Click on OK.